# Celery - I want only one instance of my task in the queue at a time

Tags: celery, django-celery, celery-task

I have a celery task that is scheduled to run every 15 minutes.  For some reason the queue gets backed up from time to time and I end up with multiple instances of the same task in the queue.  I would like celery to add the scheduled task to the queue only if it isn't there already.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is mentioned in the documentation here:

https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#entries

Usually when people want to ensure there is only instance of a task running at a time, they use a locking strategy:

https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/tutorials/task-cookbook.html#ensuring-a-task-is-only-executed-one-at-a-time

Comment: Thanks.  However, I'm not concerned merely about only one instance of the task running at a time -- I don't want two instances running back-to-back, either. If my periodic task comes around again and the previous one is still in the queue, then I'd rather just not put the new task instance in the queue at all.

Comment: Celery doesn't have a built-in way to do what you want. You could use the LOCK_EXPIRE setting in that example to ensure that the tasks are not scheduled too often or put other special values into the lock like a timestamp instead of a simple boolean to determine when it was last queued. If that isn't sufficient, then it may be best to make your own command line scheduler under supervisor instead of using celery beat.

Comment: Both [celery-singleton](https://github.com/steinitzu/celery-singleton) and [celery-once](https://github.com/cameronmaske/celery-once) can do this for you.